# Problem when installing Miktex 2.9 on win10 system

Tags: miktex, installing, windows

I download my MIkTeX-basic-x64 from this link:https://miktex.org/download.
I run the .exe program and then something like the followings happens:
[image]

I've tried the solution offered on this website for similar problems but none of them works.
Really need some help!

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX!  Did you try to install as administrator?

Comment: Did you disable the antivirus during installation?

Answer (score 1):

This question, or one like it, has been asked many times. If you are having difficulty installing MiKTeX:

1. Do not install as administrator. Even though that may work, it is not desirable in terms of security. Temporarily disabling antivirus may help, IF you first scan the entire MiKTeX download for virus.
2. Obtain The "portable" version of MiKTeX, and install it somewhere in your user directory (not in Programs). I find that this always works. For example, you can install in C:\Users\YourName\SomeFolder.
3. If you do install as portable, then you can copy the entire installation to a USB drive, and use it on another computer.

Comment: Appreciate your response! I will try them.